# Glitch with page transitioning animation in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, animation

I have recently made a dark mode for my app and noticed a weird glitch. Whenever a page is sliding, a white line appears at the edge of the sliding page. The line flashes during the animation and disappears when it is done. It may be happening even when I use lighter colors, but it's more noticeable with the dark theme. I think it's best illustrated with a picture:

[image]

This animation glitch happens with the drawer aswell, but only when I tap a button to open it and not when I use my finger to slide the drawer. It happens on both iOS and android.

Any ideas as to what may be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it is the canvas color that is showing. To change that color, just change the canvasColor in the ThemeData of your material app. If you match this color with the background color of the page that is sliding, it will not be visible.

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Main(),
  theme: ThemeData(
    canvasColor: backgroundColor //Change to match the background of the page
  ),
)
```